# How do I check if my site is banned in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: domains

I have a website which allows sexuality explicit materials for some reason. Recently, going through Google Analytics I realized that I stopped receiving traffic from Saudi Arabia. I'm very curious to know if Saudi Arabia blocked my domain name.

How do I know or check if my site is banned in Saudi Arabia? I'd love find to some quick solution online where I can just insert my domain name into an input and check.

Comment: Check this : http://serverfault.com/questions/430965/how-to-check-my-website-is-working-in-saudi-arabia

Comment: @HelpingHands, I checked all the answers, none worked.

Comment: I see..then wait for some expert to answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest quickest solution, it works even if you want to test it for any country.

I downloaded the extension [Hola](http://hola.org/), it gives Free VPN, Secure Browsing and Unrestricted Access.

All I had to was change the country to  Saudi Arabia:

[image]

It turned out my URL got blocked. It is really simple to check.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about the politics/laws involved with a nation blocking a domain, but you can access the web through an HTTP proxy in Saudi Arabia to see what it looks like from that IP.

I googled "saudi arabia proxy" and tried a few before I found one that worked on http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-sa/. I used `curl` on a Mac to test the proxy at `85.194.75.18:8080`:

```
$ curl -vx 85.194.75.18:8080 icanhazip.com                                                                                                                                                                                        
* Rebuilt URL to: icanhazip.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 85.194.75.18...
* Connected to 85.194.75.18 (85.194.75.18) port 8080 (#0)
> GET HTTP://icanhazip.com/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: icanhazip.com
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 15:37:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< X-RTFM: Learn about this site at http://bit.ly/icanhazip-faq and don't abuse the service
< X-BECOME-A-RACKER: If you're reading this, apply here: http://rackertalent.com/
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Content-Length: 13
< X-Cnection: close
< Age: 0
< 
85.194.75.18
* Connection #0 to host 85.194.75.18 left intact
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in my view since it only requires curl.